# How to give a variable multiple values?

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

I am making a (very basic) game. Therefore I need to store data for (a lot of) entities.

So I came up with this concept:

```
String[] Entity_Data = new String[EntityCount];
Entity_Data[0] = "1 12 98 45";//Or other numbers...
```

The first number could be something like hunger status or walking speed or even a X or Y coordinate.

Is there a way to give each variable in an array multiple values?

Comment: Use a class with properties, then store multiple instances in a `List<YourCustomClass>`.

Comment: One variable = one value. If you need multiple values, use something like a `List<int>` or an array

Comment: i Think you are looking for a multidimensional array, check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Comment: what about using multidimensional array or Dictionary

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To the basic question of how to store multiple values in a single variable, use something like a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), or [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx):

```
List<String> items = new List<String>() {
  "one", "two", "three"
};

Dictionary<String, String> items = new Dictionary<String, String>() {
  {"name 1", "value 1"},
  {"name 2", "value 2"}
  {"name 3", "value 3"}
};

var items = new Tuple<string, int, int>("Bad Guy", 100, 50);
```

**That said**, you're doing it wrong. Create a [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0b0thckt.aspx) and use fully qualified properties/attributes. Something like so:

```
public class Enemy {
  private Int32 MaxHitPoints;
  private Int32 CurrentHitPoints;
  private Int32 Strength;
  private Int32 Speed;
  private List<Weapons>;

  public Hit(Int32 power) {
    CurrentHitPoints = CurrentHitPoints - power;
    if (CurrentHitPoints <= 0) {
      Die();
      Explode();
      MakeAMess();
    }
  }

}
```

Etc. ... Might be worth perusing/asking questions over at [game-dev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A `Tuple` could also be useful in a collection if you want to store several objects per entry.

Comment: @aevitas Incorporated. Thanks!

Comment: This is very helpfull. But as far as I can understand now, I would have to create a class for each enemy I add... right? (Btw, I love the MakeAMess part)

Comment: You create a class for each type of game object. Whether you need multiple classes for each enemy, I can't say. If your enemies all do pretty much the same thing, you could potentially create a single class with a `EnemyType`, `EnemyImage`, etc.. Each *instance* of `Enemy` could be pretty different, depending on how flexible you make the `Enemy` class.

Comment: maybe you should create a `super type` for your game object, then inherit it based on ur needs. So if u had different types of enemies, then each should have its class, but since they all are enemies then they would share some `info/behavior/...etc`, so you would create a **super class** that defines that shared info/behavior and then for each specialized enemy u inherit this class and customize it

Comment: Thank you very much, now I know how to go on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jagged arrays, like this:

```
string[][] jaggedArray = new string[3][];

jaggedArray[0] = new string[5];
jaggedArray[1] = new string[4];
jaggedArray[2] = new string[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the fact that I love your funky spelling of "coördinate", are you aware that a potential solution is hovering right in front of your eyes, waiting to be discovered?

What is `Entity_Data`, if not a variable that can hold more than one value? And what is it that you're looking for? Exactly the same thing! Meaning, you could declare `Entity_Data` as an array of arrays ("jagged array") of `string`:

```
var entityData = new string[3][];
entityData[0] = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
entityData[1] = new string[] { "a", "b" };
entityData[2] = new string[] { "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V" };
```

I am not suggesting that this is the best possible solution, but I thought it worth pointing out to you anyway.

Comment: Is it really possible to have an array of arrays? I have tried that before but I didn't get it to work before... Btw, I wrote Coördinates like that because i'm Dutch ;)

Comment: @user2287549: Added a code example demonstrating that an array of arrays can be declared.

Answer (score 2):

You should change to Object-Oriented concept will be good. You can store any type of variable as attribute in class. If you want to get some data of attribut you should creating property to get or set attribute.

```
class Player
{
    private string _name;
    private int _hungerStatus;
    private int _walkingSpeed;
    private int _Xco;
    private int _Yco;

    // property
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
           return _name;
        }
        set
        {
           _name = value;
        }
    }
    …        
}
```

When you want to use it, you just e.g. `X = player.Name` or `player.Name = "Hero";`.

See more at http://www.dotnetperls.com/property.